# Get the percent for every answer in a voting system

Tags: php, sql, percentage

I want to get the percent of the answers I have for my question in my voting system. Here's how the code looks like:

```
# DATABASE (count)
$c_answers = sql("SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM votes
                  WHERE id_question = '1'
                 ",

                 Array(), 1);

# DATABASE (fetch)
$answers = "SELECT *
            FROM answers
            WHERE id_question = '1'
            ORDER BY answer ASC
           ";


foreach($sql->query($answers) AS $answer) {

    # DATABASE (fetch)
    $percent = sql("SELECT *
                    FROM votes
                    WHERE id_question = '1'
                    AND id_answer = '".(int)$answer['id']."'
                   ",

                   Array(), 0);


    echo '<div class="answer">';
        echo '<div class="answer-procent">';
            echo ($answer['id_answer'] + $percent['id_answer']) / $c_answers;
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="vote" data="'.(int)$answer['id'].'">';
            echo $answer['answer'];
        echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

`sql` is a function that contains all of the things a PDO database structure need. The database for `votes` and `answers` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_question` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_answer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime_voted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datetime_changed` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_question` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datetime_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have just one data in `votes` with 4 answers in `answers` and instead of `100` as it should show, it shows `2`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about PHP, but you can return all this from a single query:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.answer,
    100 * a.vote_count / t.total_count as percent
from (
    select
        a.id,
        a.answer,
        count(*) vote_count
    from
        answers a
            left outer join
        votes v
             on a.id_question = v.id_question and
                a.id = v.id_answer
    where
        a.id_question = 1
    group by
        a.id,
        a.answer
    ) a
    cross join (
      select
        count(*) total_count
      from
        votes
      where
        id_question = 1
    ) t
order by
    a.id;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e016f/14)</kbd>**

It looks to me that you're doing arithmetic with the ids themselves. In the third query you probably want to use count `again`.

Comment: Thanks! But it shows 100 even if more than one answer have votes.

Comment: @ErikEdgren sorry, I've fixed it and added a link to an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd load all the relevant records for particular question beforehand to avoid placing queries in a loop. Here's what it'd look like..

```
$votes = array('questionId' => 'rightAnswerId');
$answers = array ( 'questionId' => 'answer');

foreach ($answers as $questionId=>$answer){

    if (isset($votes[$questionId]) && $answer == $votes[$questionId]) {

       $result[] = $answer; 

    }

}

$finalResult = count($result) * 100 / count($answers);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting `0` on every answer. I putted your code inside my `foreach` loop and changed `answers` and `answer` to `answers2` and `answer2`

Comment: You don't need to put the code inside any loop. All you need to do is fetch all records for votes and answers table (for that particular question) and store it to variables.